# how to parse this array in t-sql

Tags: json, t-sql

it is not clear how to parse thies nested array

I have this json. I try to parse such:

```
declare @wjson2 nvarchar(max)
set @wjson2=N'{
  "requestBody": {
       "neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT": {
      "1": "1560993",
      "2": "1109365",
      "3": "1472360",
      "4": "739861",
      "5": "966391",
      "6": "127652",
      "7": "1082130",
      "8": "1560999",
      "9": "925470",
      "10": "1160384",
      "11": "164386",
      "12": "1118238",
      "13": "652887",
      "14": "75311",
      "15": "347861",
      "16": "1563788",
      "17": "1025063",
      "18": "131099",
      "19": "1561856"

    },

    "neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID": {
      "1": "1560993",
      "2": "1109365",
      "3": "1472360",
      "4": "739861",
      "5": "966391",
      "6": "127652",
      "7": "1082130",
      "8": "1560999",
      "9": "925470",
      "10": "1160384",
      "11": "164386",
      "12": "1118238",
      "13": "652887",
      "14": "75311",
      "15": "347861",
      "16": "1563788",
      "17": "1025063",
      "18": "131099",
      "19": "1561856"
    },
     "neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID": {
      "1": "161389036",
      "2": "161389036",
      "3": "161389036",
      "4": "161389036",
      "5": "161389036",
      "6": "161389036",
      "7": "161389036",
      "8": "161389036",
      "9": "161389036",
      "10": "161389036",
      "11": "161389036",
      "12": "161389036",
      "13": "161389036",
      "14": "161389036",
      "15": "161389036",
      "16": "161389036",
      "17": "161389036",
      "18": "161389036",
      "19": "161389036"
    }
}
}'

 

SELECT

  JSON_QUERY(@wjson2, '$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT') as neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT,
    JSON_QUERY(@wjson2, '$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID') as neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID,
JSON_QUERY(@wjson2, '$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID') as neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID
```

i want to get such result but i dont know how to parse it. Pls, help to parse such json

| id | neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT | neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID | neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1560993 | 1560993 | 161389036 |
| 2 | 1109365 | 1109365 | 161389036 |
| 19 | 1561856 | 1561856 | 161389036 |

Comment: What about the wealth of information, such as articles, existing Q&As, and documentation, didn't you understand?

Comment: I looked at the articles, but it didn't help me. Maybe you, as a guru, can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, but here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
SELECT
        A.[key] AS id,
        A.[value] AS neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID,
        B.[value] AS neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT,
        C.[value] AS neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID
FROM OPENJSON(@wjson2,'$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID') AS A
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@wjson2,'$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_VENDORMAT') AS B
    ON A.[key]=B.[key]
LEFT JOIN OPENJSON(@wjson2,'$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_EXT_PRODUCT_ID') AS C
    ON A.[key]=C.[key];
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Why i had other result if i use this code select * from openjson(@wjson2) with (neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID int '$.requestBody.neW_ITEM_EXT_QUOTE_ID')  ?   where i can read about it?

Comment: If you think a few `OPENJSON` calls is a "difficult" query, @Kirik, then you're in for a shock when you get to your first CTE.

Comment: @ThomA  i have not experense to parse nested json

Comment: If you want to read about it, then use your favourite search engine and just type `<Name of Feature> <Name of Data Engine>`, I can guarantee the documentation for this feature will be the first result.

Comment: @Kirik because this is a json array... if you change ```int``` to ```nvarchar(max)``` and add a ```AS JSON``` before the last ```)``` you can see the array